# use map2 to multiply more than two lists of matrices in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, purrr, multiplication

I have

```
A = list(a = matrix(1:4, 2), b = matrix(2:5, 2))

G = list(a = matrix(10:13, 2), b = matrix(25:28, 2))

columns <- list(a = matrix(3:4, 1), b = matrix(1:2, 1))
```

I want to make another list of cross-products of all the elements with the same name across lists, so I do `` purrr::map2(A, G, columns, `%*%`) ``. It doesn't look like `map2` allows more than two elements. Is there a workaround?

```
Error in `stop_bad_length()`:
! Index 1 must have length 1, not 2
Backtrace:
 1. purrr::map2(A, G, columns, `%*%`)
 4. purrr:::stop_bad_element_length(...)
 5. purrr:::stop_bad_length(...)
```

I also tried `purrr::pmap(list(A, G, columns), %*%)`, but no luck.

`` purrr::map2(A, G, `%*%`) `` works beautifully.

Comment: What is your expected output? `%*%` is matrix multiplication between two matrices and does not accept a 3rd argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function you are trying to apply (`'%*%'`) is a function which only takes two arguments and not three.

For your problem I would recommend `Reduce` (or `purrr::reduce`): in this case `Reduce` starts with two matrices and multiplies them. Then it multiplies the result with the third matrix. Theoretically you could go on like this.

```
lapply(seq_along(A), \(k) Reduce('%*%', list(A[[k]],G[[k]], t(columns[[k]]))))

[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]  333
[2,]  496

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]  486
[2,]  647
```

Note that I had to transpose the matrices inside `column` because they do not have the right size.

Comment: I think I placed `columns` in the wrong place. It should have been the first element.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @Cettt's approach in `tidyverse` - where we take in `list` in `pmap`, and then `reduce` with `%*%`.  Note that the the 'columns' elements needs to be `t`ransposed

```
library(purrr)
pmap(list(A, G, columns), ~ reduce(list(..1, ..2, t(..3)), `%*%`))
$a
     [,1]
[1,]  333
[2,]  496

$b
     [,1]
[1,]  486
[2,]  647
```

---

Or an option with `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(\(x, y, z) Reduce(`%*%`, list(x, y, t(z))), A, G, columns)
$a
     [,1]
[1,]  333
[2,]  496

$b
     [,1]
[1,]  486
[2,]  647
```